# Using R in VScode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

The terminal process

```
"C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\radian.exe
'--no-save', '--no-restore'" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

I can't run the R file even though I have installed radian, languageserver, and R support extension.

I have added the following to r.rtem:

```json
"terminal.integrated": {
    "shell.linux": "/bin/bash",
    "shell.windows": "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Scripts\\radian.exe"
}
```

and r.rpath:

```
"C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.2.0\\bin\\x64\\R.exe"
```